# How can I extract the value of a specific key in an HTML using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the value next to videoId into a variable.

```
var mgPerformanceTimingSettings = {
    pageType : '...',
    cdn : '...',
    videoId : '1111111111',  //Video ID
    playerVersion : '2.1.0' // Current version
};
```

My code is currently the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'url destination link'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
name_box = soup.find()
```

And I would like my name_box to return The videoId '1111111111'

And is there a way to change my coding to include everything I wrote into a function instead of procedural steps to return my desired output?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done using regex not BeautifulSoup

```
import re

....    
videoId = re.search("videoId\s+:\s+'([^']+)", response.text).group(1)
print(videoId)
# 1111111111
```

Comment: but the point is to automate the process over several websites without having to copy the chunk code

Comment: no way you can extract it using bs4 itself, regex  is required. you can use selenium to extract js variable but the variable must public